# Positioning label and input side by side

Tags: html, css, survey

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have the `p` label (red) line up to the left of the checkboxes (yellow). I've looked around a bit and still haven't got found the solution and I had also tried using different properties, but nothing seems to work.

This is what I have so far:

```css
label {
  display: block;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.mainBox {
  background-color: red;
}

#checkLabel {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainBox">
  <div id="checkLabel" class="labelClass">
    <p for="improvements">Things that should be improved in the future (Check all that apply):</p>
  </div>
  <div id="checkbox" class="rightTab">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="parking"> Parking</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="bathrooms"> Bathrooms</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="amenities"> Amenities</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="wifi"> Faster Wi-Fi
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="Accommodations"> Accommodations</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="housekeeping"> Daily Housekeeping</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="furniture"> Furniture and Linens</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="checkin&out"> Rolling Check-in/out</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="cs"> 24/7 Customer Service</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="planning"> Hotel Planning & Bookings</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add a rough sketch of what is your expected result? Is it, for every checkbox there is the `<p>` on its left? Or you want the two `div` to be side to side?

Comment: @Swellar I'm not sure how to add a snippet image I have taken on my desktop, but what I was looking for is having both divs side-by-side so that the question flows with the checkboxes along with a gap in between the two. The main project that I'm working on and to give an idea is here: https://codepen.io/jl88s/full/BOmGyO/

Comment: both divs? which div and which div?

Answer (score 1):

recommend using bootstrap for this.
install bootstrap 4 in your project and follow the link below.
This will guide you achieve your goal.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

use **col** class as shown in above link with your red tab in left column and yellow tab in right column. That's all.

Easy way out.  They have explained everything with diagrams.
using bootstrap saves you a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the `<p>` to be next to the `<input`s. Well, you could just change the `<p>`'s `display` to `inline` rather than `block`:

```
#checkLabel p {
    display: inline;
}
```

This would produce the following output:

```css
label {
  display: block;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.mainBox {
  background-color: red;
}

#checkLabel {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainBox">
  <div id="checkLabel" class="labelClass">
    <p for="improvements">Things that should be improved in the future (Check all that apply):</p>
  </div>
  <div id="checkbox" class="rightTab">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="parking"> Parking</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="bathrooms"> Bathrooms</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="amenities"> Amenities</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="wifi"> Faster Wi-Fi
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="Accommodations"> Accommodations</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="housekeeping"> Daily Housekeeping</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="furniture"> Furniture and Linens</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="checkin&out"> Rolling Check-in/out</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="cs"> 24/7 Customer Service</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="planning"> Hotel Planning & Bookings</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: Almost! In the link (https://codepen.io/jl88s/full/BOmGyO/), you see how the alignment of label and inputs are centered within the page along with a small gap in between. That's what I'm aiming for, to have the question on the left and checkboxes on the right, but on the same line.

Comment: Okay, I'll see what you want and rack my pea-sized brain for answers

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you were looking for. display:inline-block will make them come side by side but first div has a big p element so specifying width will restrict it from getting whole width. vertical-align : top will push divs to the top.

```css
label {
  display: block;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.mainBox {
  background-color: red;
 
}

#checkLabel {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  width:50%;
  vertical-align: top;
   
}
#checkbox{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainBox">
  <div id="checkLabel" class="labelClass">
    <p for="improvements">Things that should be improved in the future (Check all that apply):</p>
  </div>
  <div id="checkbox" class="rightTab">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="parking"> Parking</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="bathrooms"> Bathrooms</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="amenities"> Amenities</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="wifi"> Faster Wi-Fi
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="Accommodations"> Accommodations</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="housekeeping"> Daily Housekeeping</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="furniture"> Furniture and Linens</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="checkin&out"> Rolling Check-in/out</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="cs"> 24/7 Customer Service</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="planning"> Hotel Planning & Bookings</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understood that you want to float label on left side of those checkboxes. For that you can go for flexbox, because flexbox wrapping items of it in a box model. By default it wrap items in row direction. So what you can do just add property **display** and value **flex**, so it will wrap it's content in a row. I am adding those code in a snippet below, you will find label is taking much space, and for that you can define label class(.labelClass) width.

```css
label {
  display: block;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.mainBox {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
}

#checkLabel {
  width: 30%;
}
#checkLabel p{
  margin:0 5px;
}
#checkbox{
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainBox">
  <div id="checkLabel" class="labelClass">
    <p for="improvements">Things that should be improved in the future (Check all that apply):</p>
  </div>
  <div id="checkbox" class="rightTab">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="parking"> Parking</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="bathrooms"> Bathrooms</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="amenities"> Amenities</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="wifi"> Faster Wi-Fi
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="Accommodations"> Accommodations</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="housekeeping"> Daily Housekeeping</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="furniture"> Furniture and Linens</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="checkin&out"> Rolling Check-in/out</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="cs"> 24/7 Customer Service</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="planning"> Hotel Planning & Bookings</label>
  </div>
</div>
```